# User's PowerShell Modules Path Location on Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, powershell

Where are PowerShell modules saved to when installed with `CurrentUser` scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) user modules are saved to:

`~/.local/share/powershell/Modules`

Source: [What's New in PowerShell Core 6.0 - Filesystem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6#filesystem)